# не работает пример код реакта

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всё правильно настроено. но не отображается на экране ничего.
в чем проблема? [Полный Код](http://codepen.io/412/pen/GqBBLN)

```
    // App
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
     <Nav />
     <Header />
   </div>
    )
  }
});

// Nav
var Nav = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul className="nav nav-pills">
      <li role="presentation" className="active"><a href="#">вкладка</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">вкладка</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">вкладка</a></li>
    </ul>
    )
  }
});

// Header
var Header = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h1 className="foo">привет</h1>
    )
  }
});



React.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#mm"));
```

Comment: сыл на код  в "введите сюда описание ссылки"

Comment: в консоли первая же ошибка - TypeError: React.render is not a function

Answer (score 1):

У вас `React.render` неправильно, надо

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#mm"));
```

Тогда все работает http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOJaxK

По мотивам https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627665/error-with-basic-react-example-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function